# Connecting to MySQL Remotely from Windows with SSH

Tags: mysql

Team,

We have MySQL server running on remote machine (IP: XX.XX.XX.01) and we have SSH bastion server (IP: XX:XX:XX:02).

Appreciate, if I can get support in establishing the connection to remote MySQL server through ssh tunnel, from ODBC driver in window.

Thanks in advance.

i have tied follow this blog, but no luck.

[https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.7/en/windows-and-ssh.html#:~:text=5.5%20Connecting%20to%20MySQL%20Remotely%20from%20Windows%20with,ODBC%20application%20%28such%20as%20%20Access%29.%20More%20items](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.7/en/windows-and-ssh.html#:%7E:text=5.5%20Connecting%20to%20MySQL%20Remotely%20from%20Windows%20with,ODBC%20application%20%28such%20as%20%20Access%29.%20More%20items)

I assume, this work if both ssh and mysql server are same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `ssh` tunnel from your local host to the bastion host and from there connecting to the MySQL server's external IP with

```bash
ssh -L 3306:X.X.X.01:3306 bastion_user@X.X.X.02
```

This will open the TCP port `3306` on your local host and forward it through the tunnel to port `3306` of `X.X.X.01`. See [documentation on port forwarding](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#L%7E2).

To connect to the database your local ODBC application now needs to connect to `localhost` port `3306`.

If the database is not available on the external interface of the MySQL host (`X.X.X.01`) but you can login with `ssh` then you can [use the bastion as a jump host](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#J) and create a tunnel from your local machine directly to the MySQL host:

```bash
ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 -J bastion_user@X.X.X.02 db_host_user@X.X.X.01
```